# HD Power Saving with OpenFiler

Tags: raid, network-attached-storage, openfiler

Does OpenFiler support power saving when used with software raid? I have only seen it mentioned as "planned for the future".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched again and did not find any positive information, so I assume it is not yet possible.